# How to get output of a webpage in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say this page

`www.example.com/mypage`

returns some html that I want to parse in Actionscript.

How do i call this page from Actionscript while getting back the response in a string variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import flash.net.*

var _loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var _req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.google.com');
_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete);
_loader.load(_req);

function _onComplete(e:Event):void{
    trace(String(_loader.data));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use [URLLoader](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and load the data as [plain text](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoaderDataFormat.html#TEXT). here's some sample code.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("www.example.com/mypage"));
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseReturn);       
function parseReturn(e:Event):void {
    var response:String = (e.target as URLLoader).data;
    //do parsing here
}
```