# How to get output of a webpage in ActionScript 2

Tags: actionscript-2

For Actionscript 2.0

Let's say this page

`www.example.com/mypage`

returns some html that I want to parse in Actionscript.

How do i call this page from Actionscript while getting back the response in a string variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use LoadVars():

var lv = new LoadVars();

//if you want to pass some variables, then:
lv.var1 = "BUTTON";
lv.var2 = "1";

lv.sendAndLoad("http://www.example.com/mypage.html", lv, "POST");

lv.onLoad = loadedDotNetVars;

function loadedDotNetVars(success)
{
    if(success) 
    {
        // operation was a success
        trace(lv.varnameGotFromPage)
    }
    else 
    {
        // operation failed
    }
}

//if you dont want to send data, just get from it, then use just `lv.Load(...)` instead of `sendAndLoad(...)`

Comment: lv.varnameGotFromPage expects that the page response is in  key/value pairs: varnameGotFromPage=value1&key2=value2.
What if my page response is not in key/value pairs?
how do i load the whole response in one string variable?

Answer (score 0):

I understand. Use this code then:

```
 docXML = new XML(msg);
    XMLDrop = docXML.childNodes;
    XMLSubDrop = XMLDrop[0].childNodes;
    _root.rem_x = (parseInt(XMLSubDrop[0].firstChild));
    _root.rem_y = (parseInt(XMLSubDrop[1].firstChild));
    _root.rem_name = (XMLSubDrop[2].firstChild);
```

Comment: This looks like an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlFetcher:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

htmlFetcher.onData = function(thedata) {
    trace(thedata); //thedata is the html code
};
```

Use:

```
htmlFetcher.load("http://www.example.com/mypage");
```

to call.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could use:

page = getURL("www.example.com/mypage.html");

And it would load the page contents on the page variable.

Comment: i just need the output of the request, i don't want to load the page.

Comment: I think the page is the output of a request, right? Or maybe I don't understand the question?

Comment: Take a look at the answers of the same question for Actionscript 3 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401204/get-output-of-a-webpage-in-actionscript-3